# Why are lifetime specifiers not required [sometimes] in Rust for generics?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I was looking at the Microsoft Rust guide and while reading the generics chapters, I came across the following problem.

Consider the two following pieces of code:

```
struct Point<T>
{
    x: T,
    y: T,
}
fn main()
{
    let intro = Point{ x: "Hello", y: "World" };    
}
```

```
struct Point
{
    x: &str,
    y: &str,
}
fn main()
{
    let intro = Point{ x: "Hello", y: "World" };    
}
```

Both have x and y have the types `&str`.
Why is the compiler able to infer lifetime in first piece and not in the second?

Comment: I searched for various topics in stack overflow relating to this topic, but I couldn't really find the correct one that answers this. It'd be great if you guys pointed me towards a correct post.

Comment: The first one is equivalent to `struct Point<'a, T: 'a> { x: T, y: T}`. Since `x` and `y` have the same type `T`, they must also share the lifetime of the references in `T` (if any). In the second one you specify `&str` twice, so you might have meant either `struct Point<'a> { x: &'a str, y: &'a str }` (equivalent to the generic version) or the more permissive `struct Point<'a, 'b> { x: &'a str, y: &'b str }` or even `struct Point { x: &'static str, y: &'static str }`, etc.

Comment: Bottom line is: the compiler refuses the temptation to guess, so it requires you to specify the lifetimes of the types that mention references explicitly, as those types are not "the same", they are generic over a lifetime.

Comment: Pretend for a moment that references (`&'a u8`) were instead written like a struct, say, `Ref<'a, u8>`. `Point<&u8>` would be `Point<Ref<'_, u8>>`. In that case, the lifetime information is part of the generic argument, hence why `Point` itself doesn't need to infer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case:

```rust
struct Point<T>
{
    x: T,
    y: T,
}
fn main()
{
    let intro = Point{ x: "Hello", y: "World" };    
}
```

The type definition is valid for whatever T, and especially for whatever lifetime the reference have if there are references. It's a generics, it's meant to adapt (and to lead to several different "real" structs if necessary).

The concrete struct you use is for `T` being `&'static str` but it could be another lifetime.

In the second  case

```rust
struct Point
{
    x: &str,
    y: &str,
}
fn main()
{
    let intro = Point{ x: "Hello", y: "World" };    
}
```

There's no generic. So it must be a completely defined type. Meaning there has to be a lifetime if there are references. You don't specify the lifetime, so it's an error.

If you want to have only the lifetime free to decide, then it's a generic again:

```rust
struct Point<'a> {
    x: &'a str,
    y: &'a str,
}
fn main()
{
    let intro = Point{ x: "Hello", y: "World" };    
}
```

Alternatively, if you want your Point to be only valid for static references, you can define it as

```rust
struct Point {
    x: &'static str,
    y: &'static str,
}
```